# OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO Error For Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oracle, oracle-call-interface

I am facing an issue with rake. When I give rake, rake fails with the following error:

```
/Ruby/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/oci8.rb:228 - ORA-28002: the password will expire within 5 days
```

The problem here is that OCILogon will give a status as OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO which i believe is not handled in evn.c

So when I dug up into the code, I found that evn.c did indeed have check only for OCI_SUCCESS
But then, I changed the code to something like this in the function oci8_logon present in env.c of ruby:

```
rv = OCILogon(envh->hp, envh->errhp, &svchp,
            u.ptr, u.len, p.ptr, p.len, d.ptr, d.len);

if (rv != OCI_SUCCESS && rv != OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO) {
    oci8_raise(envh->errhp, rv, NULL);
  }
```

Still I am facing the same issue.
I verified the return value (rv) it is coming as 1 which from oci.h, I verified to be OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO

Any idea what I need to do next?

PS: I don't want to go and change the password expiry behavior on the oracle side by changing the Profile to which the account is associated. I need a workaround at ruby level.

Answer (score 0):

Change your comparison to

```
if (rv != OCI_SUCCESS && rv != OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
                      ^^ logical AND instead of logical OR
```

Share and enjoy.

---

EDIT:
After further consideration, I think this would be clearer if it was rewritten to make positive comparisons instead of negative comparisons:

```
rv = OCILogon(envh->hp, envh->errhp, &svchp,    
            u.ptr, u.len, p.ptr, p.len, d.ptr, d.len);    

if (rv == OCI_SUCCESS || rv == OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO)
  {
  /* Code to perform when OCILogon succeeds */
  }
else
  {
  /* Code to perform when OCILogon fails */

  oci8_raise(envh->errhp, rv, NULL);
  }
```

And so it goes...

Comment: Thanks Bob. But if you see the update on the post, I mentioned that even when the oci8_raise call is not made, I get an invalid handle error. It seems like when the logon returns an OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO, the subsequent handle operations become invalid. I'm not sure about this. But is there a workaround for this?

Comment: I suggest that if the return value is OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO then OCIErrorGet should be called repeatedly until OCI_NO_DATA is returned to clear any outstanding errors/warnings.  For testing purposes those warnings and/or errors should be either displayed somewhere or dumped to a file so you can see what the warnings/errors might be.  (And I agree that after OCI_SUCCESS_WITH_INFO there should be no errors).  I don't understand why this might affect things but it's something to try.

Comment: I didn't try the repeated call of OCIErrorGet. Worth a try anyway. I called OCIErrorGet once and got the "Password will expire in 7 days" message.